# Code execution in Stack in Cortex-M4

Tags: assembly, stack, arm, runtime

I am trying to copy code from code memory to stack and then use that code in stack for execution. I am using the following function

```
;Personal Function
IMPORT extfunc
EXPORT func
func
LDR R0,=extfunc;Function  in C 
LDR R1,=0x00000000;Counter for Counting instructions when i make code generic
PUSH {LR};For nested call       
ADD R3,SP,#0x00;move 
SUB SP,#0x10;As stack grows upwards, we just make space for 10 instructions for testing
ADD R5,SP,#0x0;Where we branch after copying
LOOP
LDR SP,[R0];Load in stack instruction
ADD R1,R1,#0x01;instruction count
ADD R0,#0x04;next C instruction address 
ADD SP,#0x04;next instruction address
CMP R1,#0x10;Copy 10 instructions
BLT LOOP
ADD R0,PC,#0x0C;Get ready for branching
ADD LR,R0,#0x00;LR prepared
ADD PC,R5,#0x00;GO
ADD SP,R3,#0x00;When we return restore the SP
POP {LR}
BX LR
```

but I get the following errors

> startup_XMC4500.s(335): error: A1477E: This register combination results in UNPREDICTABLE behaviour
>
> startup_XMC4500.s(336): error: A1477E: This register combination results in UNPREDICTABLE behaviour

Apparently you can't move PC to any arbitrary address calculated at run time, can anyone tell me a workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't manipulate special registers by adding registers with some value and storing them back you'll have to use explicit load or store instructions..